Mysql is crashing because of out-of-memory despite having enough ram
I have a mysql pod in my k8s cluster, here is the yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql9
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql9
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql9
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:8
          name: mysql
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '2000m'
              memory: '12000Mi'
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: username
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: database
            - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
              value: 'false'
            - name: MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD
              value: 'false'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql9-pv-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            - name: mysql9-config
              mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
      volumes:
        - name: mysql9-pv-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql9-pv-claim
        - name: mysql9-config
          configMap:
            name: mysql9-config

The mounted config looks like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql9-config
data:
  my.cnf: |
    [client]
    port = 3306
    socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

    [mysqld]
    user = mysql
    port = 3306
    socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    mysql_native_password=ON

    # Basic Settings
    basedir = /usr
    datadir = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir = /tmp
    pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    # log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

    # Server Performance
    skip-name-resolve
    max_connections = 3000
    table_open_cache = 4000
    table_open_cache_instances = 8
    thread_cache_size = 50

    # Memory Settings
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9G
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 9
    innodb_log_file_size = 2G  # Adjust this based on your transaction log needs
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
    innodb_file_per_table = 1
    innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
    innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
    innodb_read_io_threads = 8
    innodb_write_io_threads = 8
    innodb_io_capacity = 250
    innodb_io_capacity_max = 500
    innodb_purge_threads = 4

    # Caching and I/O
    # query_cache_type = 0
    # query_cache_size = 0
    tmp_table_size = 256M
    max_heap_table_size = 256M
    # join_buffer_size = 16M
    # sort_buffer_size = 4M
    # read_buffer_size = 4M
    # read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M

    # Character Set and Collation
    character-set-server = utf8mb4
    collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci

    # Binary Logging - Recommended for Replication and Point-in-Time Recovery
    # log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
    # expire_logs_days = 7
    # sync_binlog = 1
    # binlog_format = ROW

    # Error Log Settings
    # log_error_verbosity = 3

    # Security
    max_allowed_packet = 64M
    sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    innodb_strict_mode = 1

    # Additional Settings
    performance_schema = ON
    event_scheduler = ON
    default_storage_engine = InnoDB

    # Adjusting InnoDB Autoinc Lock Mode
    innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2

    [mysqldump]
    quick
    quote-names

    [mysql]
    no-auto-rehash

And even though I set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 9GB and resource limits to 12gb, it somehow ran out of memory. How is it possible? What could take up another 3gb and what should I change so that it doesnt happen in future?

What does the log say? Is it oom killer reaping it, or is mysql crashing?

@vidarlo The error is: OOMKilled - exit code: 137

It probably requests more memory than allowed. You should configure limits for the pod to match what you tell MySQL to use, and possily set the defaults for your namespace.

What is exactly difference between resources.request and resources.limit? And isn't it weird that mysql requests so much memory even though innodb_buffer_pool_size is 9GB?

max_connections = 3000 -- change to 300
If that does not suffice, change innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9G to 8G.
If both of those fail, provide the info in https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning for further analysis.
